# Solution to implicit definition of a function

Tags: summation, systems-of-equations

I would like to find the function defined on $x \in [-1,1]$ that satisfies
$$
f(-x) = - f(x), \quad f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty
\left[ f\left(\frac{4}{2n+3-x}-1\right) - f\left(\frac{4}{2n+3+x}-1\right)\right]$$

But other than making educated guesses I am kind of stumped.

Are there techniques for solving this type of equation? Or systematically constructing approximate solutions? (Does this type of equation have a name ?)

Comment: Could there be a typo? I mean, if $f(x) = -f(x)$, then $2f(x) = 0$ for every $x$, hence $f$ is the zero function.

Comment: @Algebrus typo fixed. Thank you!