# Steady state distribution of a generalised gauss map

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

### Question

Consider the map $g:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ given by
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
1 - \Big\lceil \frac{1}{x} \Big\rceil + \frac{1}{x} & x \leq 1/2
\\
\Big\lceil \frac{1}{1-x} \Big\rceil - \frac{1}{1-x} & x > 1/2
\end{cases}
$$
This function is plotted below

[image]

I would like to calculate the steady state distribution (aka invariant measure, aka leading eigenfunction) $m(x)$ obtained for generic initial values $x_0$ by repeated application of the map
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f \circ g^k(x_0) \to \int f(x) m(x) dx.
$$

The key properties of interest to me are

- The density at the extremal points of the interval $\lim_{x \to 0} m(x) = \lim_{x \to 1} m(x)$
- The average $\int_0^1 \log ( \min(x,1-x) ) m(x) dx = 2 \int_0^{1/2} \log (x) m(x) dx$

### Context

This is related to the well known Gauss map $h:[0,1] \to [0,1]$
$$
h(x) = \frac{1}{x} - \Big\lfloor \frac{1}{x} \Big\rfloor
$$
in the following way
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
1 - h(x) & x \leq 1/2
\\
h(1-x) & x > 1/2
\end{cases}
$$
(expect at the measure zero set of points $1/\min(x,1-x) \in \mathbb{N}$).

For $h(x)$ the steady state distribution is known, and given by
$$
m_h(x) = \frac{1}{\log 2} \frac{1}{1+x}
$$

In this case the equivalent properties of interest are

- $\lim_{x\to 0}m_h(x) = 1 / \log 2$
- $\int_0^1 dx \log (x) m_h(x) dx = \pi^2/(12 \log 2)$ (Levy's constant)

Operationally we can understand $g(x)$ as being a generalisation of the Gauss map which treat cases of $x$ very close to $0$, and $x$ very close to $1$ symmetrically.

I would like to find the equivalent properties for the map $g(x)$.

### My progress

I detail my attempt at generalising the calculation of $m_h(x)$ to the case of interest. This yields an implicit equation ($**$) for the cumulative distribution function, however I have not been able to solve this thus far. Moreover, I do not know if this approach is the correct one, so any pointers will be appreciated.

Explicitly we are interested in solutions to the equation
$$
m(x) = \int_0^1 d y \delta(x - g(y))m(y)
\tag{$*$}
$$
we write $g(x)$ in the following form
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
1 - n + \frac{1}{x} & \qquad \text{for} \qquad \frac{1}{n} \leq x < \frac{1}{n-1}, \quad n = 3 , 4 ,5 , 6 \ldots
\\
n - \frac{1}{1-x}  & \qquad \text{for} \qquad \frac{n-1}{n} \leq x < \frac{n-2}{n-1}, \quad n = 3 , 4 ,5 , 6 \ldots
\end{cases}
$$
Substituting this in to ($*$) we obtain
$$
m(x) = \sum_{n=3}^\infty \left[ \frac{m\left(\frac{1}{n-1+x}\right)}{(n-1+x)^2} + \frac{m\left(1-\frac{1}{n-x}\right)}{(n-x)^2} \right]
$$
We integrate this to obtain
$$
c(x) = \sum_{n=3}^\infty \left[ c\left( \frac{1}{n-1} \right) - c\left( \frac{1}{n-1+x} \right) + c\left( 1- \frac{1}{n} \right) - c\left( 1- \frac{1}{n-x} \right) \right]
$$
where $c(x) = \int_0^x m(y) dy$ is the cumulative distribution function. The expected symmetry of the distribution $m(x) = m(1-x)$ allows for some simplification, specifically we use $c(x) = 1 - c(1-x)$ to obtain
$$
c(x) = \sum_{n=3}^\infty \left[ c\left( \frac{1}{n-1} \right) - c\left( \frac{1}{n-1+x} \right) - c\left( \frac{1}{n} \right) + c\left( \frac{1}{n-x} \right) \right]
$$
The constant terms telescope and we obtain
$$
\begin{equation}
c(x) = 1 - c(1-x) = \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{n=3}^\infty \left[ c\left( \frac{1}{n-x} \right) - c\left( \frac{1}{n-1+x} \right) \right]
\tag{$**$}
\end{equation}
$$
where we have used that $c(1/2)=1/2$.

Unfortunately I am unable to make progress from here. Some futzing around and re-writing [yields a different form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4336183/solution-to-implicit-definition-of-a-function), but no progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I muddled through. For anyone interested, the solution is
$$
c(x) = \frac{\log\left(1+\frac{x \phi^2}{1- x + \phi}\right)}{\log\left(1 +\phi\right)}
$$
where $\phi = \tfrac12(1 + \sqrt{5})$ is the golden ratio. Using this form for $c(x)$ other properties of interest may be readily calculated.

I am still interested in other answers which explain how the problem might be tackled efficiently, as my answer was basically found by guesswork.